# Allowing 3 attempts at game - php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop Iteration in Php Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892506/loop-iteration-in-php-game)

Trying to allow the user to guess at "1" movie, three times, if they dont get it, it tells them the right answer (which is variable: $rand_keys). It also deducts guesses and displays the amount of guesses left (possible error with $guesses variable?).

Whats going wrong here? Please show me a possible solution.

```
<style type="text/css">
input {border:1px solid #ADD8E6; font-size:1.2em;}
input.spec {background-color:#ddd;}
</style>
<?php
    echo "<fieldset><h1><legend>Testing your Academy Award Trivia</h1>";
    $ages['Casablanca'] = "1943";
    $ages['Around The World in 80 Days'] = "1956";
    $ages['Patton'] = "1970";
    $ages['Annie Hall'] = "1977";
    $ages['Chariots of Fire'] = "1981";
    $ages['Dances With Wolves'] = "1990";
    $ages['Crash'] = "2005";
    $ages['The Departed'] = "2006";

    $rand_keys = array_rand($ages, 1);

    $guesses = 3;

?>
<form method='post' name="inputyear" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
Give the year below won academy award<br><br>
<Strong>Movie:</strong> <input type='text' name='movie' class="spec" value='<?= $rand_keys ?>'     readonly='readonly' /><br><br>
<Strong>Year it Won the Oscar:</Strong> <input type='text' name='year' size="30" /><br/><br>
<strong>You have: </strong> <?php $guesses; ?> guesses left<br><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value="Get Result" onClick="makeGuess()" />
</form>

<?php
$movie = isset($_POST['movie']) ? $_POST['movie'] : false;
$guessedYear = isset($_POST['year']) ? (int) $_POST['year'] : false;
if ($movie && $guessedYear) {
    $realyear = $ages[$movie];
}
@$_SESSION[$movie]['$guesses']++;
if ($realyear && $_SESSION[$movie]['$guesses'] < 3) {

    if ($guessedYear == $realyear) {
        echo "Correct! " . "during year " . $realyear;
    }
    if ($guessedYear < $realyear) {
        echo "Wrong, year too low";
        $guesses--;
    }
    if ($guessedYear > $realyear) {
        echo "Wrong, year too high";
        $guesses--;
    }

} elseif ($_SESSION[$movie]['$guesses'] >= 3) {
    echo "Sorry, too many tries. the answer was " . $realyear;
} else {
    echo "Sorry, You managed not to pick a year. Please try again";
    $_SESSION[$movie]['guesscount']--;
}
?>
```

Comment: you have already asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892506/loop-iteration-in-php-game/4892529

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is in the answers on your other question. Stop ignoring them!

Comment: Well, no, none of them worked :)

Comment: @Yanick: That link explains why "read the [expletive] manual" comments are poor style. I have a feeling that same ethic applies to "accept some [expletive] answers". I don't know why people do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing data in cookies I recommend you encrypt it. If it's not encrypted then one could open up the session cookie and reset their score.  (I'm not sure how serious this application is, but from a commercial point of view, encryption is *always* a good idea.)